# It is possible to use Xpath function in order to read the date value

Tags: xpath

Since i am new to Xpath i want to ask if it is possible to use Xpath function in order to read the date value in the following

```
<div id="qa-case"> 
<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-01-12T02:41:00Z"></time>
</div>
```

What I want is the value in the datetime. Is that possible to read it using something like this

```
//*[@id="qa-case"]fn:string(datetime)
```

What i expect is to have an text showing me 2015-01-12T02:41:00Z

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not know what version of XPath you are using. In XPath 1.0, functions must be wrapped around everything else because they cannot be steps in a path expression:

```
string(//div[@id = 'qa-case']/time/@datetime)
```

This only works with exactly one `time` element node and thus with one `datetime` attribute.

---

In XPath 2.0 you could also do

```
//div[@id = 'qa-case']/time/@datetime/string()
```

The result, in both cases, is

```
2015-01-12T02:41:00Z
```

To give a more specific answer, we would need to know more about the environment you use XPath in (say, XSLT).

Answer (score 0):

To get just the text, you don't really need any date functions, just //div[@id="qa-case"]/@datetime

If you want to convert to a more readable format you cna then use date-specific XPath functions, for example:

```
<p>Today is <xsl:value-of="fn:day-from-dateTime(@datetime)" </p>
```

Comment: We do not know whether the OP uses XPath with XSLT. It's the `value-of` facility that extracts the string value of `@datetime`. The XPath expression `//div[@id="qa-case"]/@datetime` on its own does not return just the text, it returns a whole attribute node.

Comment: Matthias - I know that, but it's not like the attribute will have children elements or anything like that so KISS ;)

Comment: You misunderstood I'm afraid. It's not a theoretical consideration, but some XPath engines actually return `datetime="2015-01-12T02:41:00Z"` as the result of `//div[@id="qa-case"]/@datetime`. Most online XPath testers do, for example.